# Mostrar pantallazo de AShot Selenium en AllureReport

Tags: selenium

He instalado la dependencia de AShot para poder usar sus características a la hora de usarlo con Selenium. Quiero mostrar los pantallazos en el plugin Allure de Jenkins. Hasta ahora lo hacía sin AShot asi y mostraba el pantallazo bien en el informe de esta manera:

```
@Attachment
private static byte[] makeScreenShotAttachment(WebDriver driver) {
    byte[] screenShot = null;      
    screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
   
        try {
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/pantallazos/" + new 
            Date().getTime()".png"), 
            screenShot);              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error al generar el pantallazo", e);
        }
    
    return screenShot;
}

 @Step("Pantallazo")
    public static byte[] makeScreenShot(WebDriver driver) {
        return makeScreenShotAttachment(driver);
    }
```

Ahora para mostralo con AShot lo he intentando de varias maneras(todas muestran bien la imagen en mi pc local), la última así:

```
@Attachment
private static BufferedImage screenshotFullAshotAttachment(WebDriver driver) {
   BufferedImage bi = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)). 
   takeScreenshot(driver).getImage();

   try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("C:/pantallazos/" + new Date().getTime() + ".png"));
     
   } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.error("Error al generar el pantallazo", e);
   }
        
   return bi;
}



 @Step("Pantallazo completo")
    public static BufferedImage screenshotFullAshot(WebDriver driver) {
        return screenshotFullAshotAttachment(driver);
    }
```

Lo que se muestra en el informe de Allure en Jenkins en vez de la imagen es esto:

```
BufferedImage@350a5c9: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@3ce9de49 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 2560 height = 932 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
```

Gracias.

Comment: Estimado, ¿es necesario que incluyas el AShot como capturador de evidencias vs la forma tradicional ? debes igual tener claro que si quieres integrar algo anexo a como esta recibiendo la informacion el allure o la libreria que sea, tienes una probalidad que la integracion no funcione, te recomiendo continuar con la forma que te funcionaba, y probar el AShot con otro estilo de reporte que no te de conflictos. a menos que sea estrictamente necesario incluir el AShot a solicitud cliente o empresa